# why can kem_cache->node assigned with address or array_cache?

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

here is a function in mm/slab.c which appears in boot initialization of kmem_cache. I don't understand this function and what actually is array_cache used which is kmem_cache->array.

```
static void setup_node_pointer(struct kmem_cache *cachep)
{
        cachep->node = (struct kmem_cache_node **)&cachep->array[nr_cpu_ids];
}
```

can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the comment right on top of that function?

```
/*
 * The memory after the last cpu cache pointer is used for the
 * the node pointer.
 */
```

The slab allocator is using extra pointer space in the `array` variable for node pointer storage (instead of `array_cache` pointers). This is hinted at by the note above the `array` variable in `slab_def.h`:

```
/* 6) per-cpu/per-node data, touched during every alloc/free */
/*
 * We put array[] at the end of kmem_cache, because we want to size
 * this array to nr_cpu_ids slots instead of NR_CPUS
 * (see kmem_cache_init())
 * We still use [NR_CPUS] and not [1] or [0] because cache_cache
 * is statically defined, so we reserve the max number of cpus.
 *
 * We also need to guarantee that the list is able to accomodate a
 * pointer for each node since "nodelists" uses the remainder of
 * available pointers.
 */
struct kmem_cache_node **node;
struct array_cache *array[NR_CPUS + MAX_NUMNODES];
```

Comment: I saw that, but I didn't comprehend it until now, but I still didn't get that the array_caches do. I mean kmem_cache_node manages memory for each node, and maintain those slab lists, but what about array_cache. It seems to be related to per cpu memory. New to numa and kernel memory, so pointing out a reference would be fine too instead of explaining the mechanism. I am just overwhelmed by too many documents and few of them explain how kmem_cache works.